# Author names are being replaced by lines in natbib using aer style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm having a dashed line issue using natbib and having replaced with a dashed line. This is similar to previously posted issues (see [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74301/name-of-authors-in-the-references-is-replaced-by-a-dashed-line), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366508/biblatex-apa-replace-author-name-by-dash-in-case-of-multiple-works-by-same-aut), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67029/printing-recurrent-author-names-instead-of-a-dash)) but none of these are in `aer` style specifically. How can I stop dashed lines from showing up in my references? `dashed=false` does not work for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mini.bib}
@unpublished{bgs2015mac,
  title={Memory, Attention and Choice},
  author={Bordalo, Pedro and Gennaioli, Nicola and Shleifer, Andrei},
  note={Mimeo, Harvard University},
  year={2017}
}

@unpublished{bgs2019mac,
  title={Memory, Attention and Choice},
  author={Bordalo, Pedro and Gennaioli, Nicola and Shleifer, Andrei},
  note={Mimeo, Harvard University},
  year={2020}
}

\end{filecontents}


\raggedbottom
%\input{tcilatex}
\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{My Paper Title} \\
\bigskip }

\maketitle


\nocite{*} 

\bibliographystyle{aer}
\bibliography{mini}

\end{document}
```

produces:
[image]

Comment: The `aer` bib style is programmed to replace repeated author names with em-dashes. If you do like this setting, you should probably not be using the `aer` bib style to begin with.

Comment: I agree, it just that this is my PI's preferred style so I can't really change it

Comment: In that case, just inform your PI that the `aer` bibliography style is programmed to substitute repeated authors' names with em-dashes and that loading the `natbib` citation management system cannot affect this programming decision. Leave it up to him/her to decide whether it's necessary to switch to a different bibliography style. (If he/she does decide on such a switch, you could recommend the `plainnat` bibliography style...)

Comment: Good advice, thanks @Mico!

Comment: @Mico the disadvantage of this is that author names are no longer bolded

Comment: Life is a series of compromises, isn't it? If you really need the authors' names to be boldfaced, please post a new query and ask how this may be achieved while using `natbib` and, say, the `plainnat` bibliography style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by using the closely related `AER` argument of the `AEA` document class

```
\documentclass[AER]{AEA} %%% change here
\usepackage{times}

...

\bibliographystyle{aea}  %% change here
\bibliography{mini}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: mine still doesn't work even after the changes you recommended. I am I missing something?